# FuncAnimation update function not running

Tags: python

I am attempting to use the FuncAnimation function to show a series of scatterplots one by one. I have 290 scatterplots that I want to show separately, starting with scatterplot 1, then deleting it and showing scatterplot 2, and so on. However, I am having trouble understanding the function and getting it to work. The relevant code is:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat = ax.scatter([],[])

def draw():
    return scat

def update(frame):
    print("WE MADE IT")
    ax.cla()
    x_pts = []
    y_pts = []
    print(frame)

    destination = main(frame)

    for dst in range(0,len(destination)):
        x_pts.append(int(abs(destination[dst][0][0])))
        y_pts.append(int(abs(destination[dst][0][1])))

    print("Before offsets")

    scat.set_offsets(list(zip(x_pts,y_pts)))
    print("after offsets")
    frame+=1

frame = 0

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=200, frames = len(numbers_data),init_func=draw,fargs=(frame,))
print("Right before show")
plt.show()
```

I am receiving the output "Right before show" and the error message: "UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you output the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()`. warnings.warn(." Can someone please help me identify what is causing the error and how to solve it?